# How to make Simple WCF Service work in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rest, wcf

I've been following tutorial [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) and trying to host a simple REST Server using WCF. Basically, I created the WCF interface and class file as described in the tutorial:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GET/{msg}/{msg2}")]
    string GetRequest(string msg, string msg2);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/PUT/{msg}")]
    void PutRequest(string msg, Stream contents);
}
```

and the concrete class:

```
class Service : IService
{
    static string Message = "Hello";

    public string GetRequest(string msg, string msg2)
    {
        return Message + msg + msg2;
    }

    public void PutRequest(string msg, Stream contents)
    {
        Service.Message = msg + msg + msg;

        string input = new StreamReader(contents).ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("In service, input = {0}", input);
    }
}
```

These 2 WCF service classes work perfecting in a **Console Application** I created. Here is how "Main" looks like. **When I submit a GET request to the Console Application, I get a 200 OK**:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service)))
             {
                 var ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new   WebHttpBinding(), new Uri("http://1.10.100.126:8899/MyService"));

                 ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                 host.Open();
                 Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
                 Console.ReadLine();
                 host.Close();
             }
        }


    }
```

}

However, when I want to use those 2 classes in a **WPF Application**, they don't work anymore. Here is the MainWindow class for the WPF Application. **When I submit a GET Request to the WPF Application, I get error 502 BAD GATEWAY**:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service)))
            {
                var ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), new Uri("http://1.10.100.126:8899/MyService"));

                ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

How do you make those 2 WCF classes work with a simple empty WPF Application project? **Why does those 2 WCF classes work with an empty Console Application project, but not an empty WPF Application Project?**

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` will not cause the thread to pause in this case. So the `host` will close immediately after it is opened. You probably should move `host.Close` to some "exit" button. You would need to make the `host` variable a member variable for that to work.

Comment: I've tried to outright remove the Console.Readline(), and host.Close() lines from my WPF Application. I still get 502 though, don't think host closing right after opening is the reason. Maybe the host is just not opening?

Comment: Can you show how do you do your `GET` request?

Comment: You need also to remove the `using` syntax. `using` will dispose your `host` object. Also, I think you should make the `host` an instance variable.

Comment: @Alisson I test my GET requests using Fiddler, so basically a GET Request to "http://1.10.100.126:8899/MyService/GET/a/b", that's for both the WPF and Console

Comment: They are different scenarios. What I meant is: can you share the part of the code in your WPF you are getting this error? I'm going to give you a sample as stated by @YacoubMassad, just try it and give us a feedback.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, Hey I think that was it, removing the "using" syntax made it work in WPF

Comment: @Alisson I'm not quite sure what you mean, but just removing that "using" line and declaring "var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service))" by itself above the ep variable fixed everything

Comment: *"When I submit a GET Request to the WPF Application, I get error 502 BAD GATEWAY..."* where is the code used to submit your GET? I can't find it in your code. You can't just get rid of `using`, it's not a good practice. I think @YacoubMassad asked you to do so, just to make sure this was the problem. Answer my question so we can help you improving your code.

Comment: @Alisson Hey Alisson, basically this WPF Application was supposed to act as a REST server host, the GET Request comes from an entirely different client application that is not even in C#. I was just saying I submitted a GET or PUT request in Fiddler just to test the REST Server side is correctly receiving the requests.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean. So you might want to consider the **second** option in my answer, because it will keep the `ServiceHost` open until the application gets closed, then it gracefully disposes/closes the host. Try it and let me know if it works as expected in your scenario, and I'm sorry for my misunderstood.

Comment: I edited my answer, and inverted it. The first approach is what you might want.

Comment: @Alisson Also, the examples in the question I gave is completely not what I am doing. I actually have a full blown GUI created in WPF already, I just need to add REST Host code to it using WCF and it wasn't working. The ServiceHost code basically will be added to a custom HttpEndPoint class I had, it won't be added to the MainWindow class. I striped out everything because I tested the WCF on an empty project and it wasn't working. I figured the empty project problem should be my project's problem too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving you a complete, thorough answer on how to properly host a WCF service properly in a WPF application is really a bit too broad, but here are some pointers.

You have a few major problems with your WPF attempt:

1. You're attempting to host the service on the UI thread, a big no-no in GUI design and programming.  If you got it working the way you have it, you'd lock your UI and the user wouldn't be able to do anything but force-close your application.
2. You're handling it all in a code behind for a Window - WPF encourages the MVVM pattern, which guides you to separate concerns of how your view (window, controls, etc.) is rendered vs. what services are used/hosted/consumed.
3. You're attempting to block the thread by using `Console.ReadLine()` in a GUI application, where there is no `Console` listening - so `Console.ReadLine()` is just returning immediately (but if you did manage to block the thread, you'd be back to problem #1).

For a full tutorial on how to do what you're attempting with better design principles, see the following [blog](https://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/wcf-simplified-part-7-hosting-a-wcf-service-using-wpf/)

Some highlights from that:

1. Create some controls (e.g. buttons that say 'Start' and 'Stop') to start and stop your service.
2. Wire up those buttons to the logic to start your service and stop your service respectively.

There's definitely improvements that could be made there - starting and managing the lifetime of the service, using the Commanding model in WPF, using the TPL or a BackgroundWorker to run the service in a different thread, making fuller usage of the MVVM pattern - but it's a start.